# Access mdb file Cannot reference itself

Tags: ms-access

I have an access database I am migrating from an older version. I have a form with a grid on it. When I right click on the object name and select Definition I get a popup that says "Cannot jump to 'grdProcedureList' because it is in the library 'C:\RecipeManager\TechParamsMgr_GW new 64 bit.mdb' which is not currently referenced.' That is the full path an name of the .mdb I'm working in.

I checked the references, there are none missing. I reregistered MSflxgrd.ocx and rebooted.

Comment: Try naming the file as it was. And the FlexGrid OCX is not 64-bit as far as I know.